# Possible to import Angular 16 based Web Component libraries into an Angular 10 project?

Tags: angular, angular-elements

I have an Angular application that is currently stuck on Angular 10 because the main consumer of the application's two core libraries is running in Angular 10 and cannot upgrade for a while (understanding that ng10 has been out of support for some time now).

I would like to upgrade my application to the latest version of Angular and try to utilize Angular elements to convert my Angular libraries to web components that can be imported into any Angular project running Angular 10 or greater.

Should it be possible to do this? Understanding that the Angular 10 application that currently imports my Angular 10 based libraries will have to refactor their methods of interacting with my libraries when I export them as web components (authored in Angular 14, 15 or 16).